# jQuery :contains(unicode_characters)

Tags: jquery, unicode, css-selectors, contains

I have an element like this:

```
<span class="tool_tip" title="The full title">The ful&#8230;</span>
```

This seems to work:

```
jQuery('span:contains(…)');
```

But this does not:

```
jQuery('span:contains(&#8230;)');
```

I am pretty sure that it would be bad to use the first one because if someone else saves the file, or the browser decides to get the file in a different character set for some reason things will not work.

There has to be a way to properly select this span, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turns out, the proper way to do this is:

```
jQuery('span:contains(\u2026)');
```

In other words:

Use the hex value instead of the decimal value.